# Unable to get an image from API

Tags: angular, typescript, api

So i'm trying to get a pokemon img and name from https://pokeapi.co/ and show it in my webapp.

while runnig the code i got two problems
[the problems that i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVGLl.png)

here's the search function:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTuvV.png)

and the data service code :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATMo3.png)

here's all the code https://github.com/tahatal7a/PokeSearch

Comment: Next time, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and additionally please paste your code into the question instead of using screenshots. You shouldn't expect the average user to sift through your entire codebase for a localized error. That being said, your error pointed me in the direction of template literals not being interpreted as such. Check my answer for a potential solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your error screenshot lead me to [this line](https://github.com/tahatal7a/PokeSearch/blob/master/src/app/data/data.service.ts#L11) that uses template literals that are not enclosed in backticks. Additionally, `this.url` already has a leading `/` appended to it, so there's no need to add one in the URL passes to `http.get`.

Replace:

```js
return this.http.get('${this.url}/${name}')
```

with:

```js
return this.http.get(`${this.url}${name}`)
```

[Relevant MDN page on template literals.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: the http error is fixed but i'm not sure why i still got the "failed to load ressources: ..."

Comment: Log the URL you are attempting to request and try and visit it in the web browser. If it's 404'ing, then you know your request URL is malformed in some way. Make sure to remove that extra `/` I mentioned.